# How do I know the exceptions that can be thrown using the new v4 API?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

In the V3 Datastax driver, the Session.execute method clearly declares what exceptions are thrown and my code will catch and deal with appropriately:

[image: V3 Javadoc Screenshot]

But in V4, the CqlSession.execute method does not declare that it throws any exceptions.  However if I give it a bad query, it does throw an exception.

[image: V4 Javadoc Screenshot]

How am I supposed to do Exception Handling with this new API without knowing all of the exceptions that could be thrown?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd like to make a friendly request and ask that you paste the outputs in text instead of screenshots. A lot of the engineers who answer questions here respond during their free time on their mobile devices and screenshots are very difficult to read. It would make it easier to help you if you paste the text instead. For reference, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The Cassandra Java driver was completely refactored in version 4.0 and it is not binary-compatible with version 3.x (or earlier releases) so the API docs in earlier versions is just not comparable to v4.

Having said that, [the API doc for `com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.14/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/servererrors/package-tree.html) lists all the possible exceptions that the driver will throw depending on the response from the cluster:

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.CoordinatorException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.ProtocolError
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.QueryExecutionException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.BootstrappingException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.CDCWriteFailureException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.FunctionFailureException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.OverloadedException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.QueryConsistencyException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.CASWriteUnknownException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.ReadFailureException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.ReadTimeoutException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.WriteFailureException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.WriteTimeoutException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.TruncateException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.UnavailableException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.QueryValidationException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.AlreadyExistsException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidConfigurationInQueryException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.SyntaxError
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.UnauthorizedException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.ServerError
```

The [API doc for `com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.14/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/package-tree.html) has a list of client-side exceptions that can be thrown:

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverExecutionException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.InvalidKeyspaceException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NodeUnavailableException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.RequestThrottlingException
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.UnsupportedProtocolVersionException
```

For what it's worth, the [Java driver doc Retries page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/retries/) is a good resource for understanding when exceptions are thrown and why. Cheers!